# Почему golang кодирует символ строки только в byte(uint8) и rune(int32)?

Tags: golang, типы-данных

Добрый день.
Вопрос с примером, имеем:

```
charLine := "слово" 
fmt.Println(charLine) // кодирует кириллицу в по 2 байта на каждый символ. По дефолту тип элементов(символов) byte т.е. uint8
```

Вопрос

1. Почему я не могу явно указать (сколько бит отводить)т.е. сказать типа делай int16 для элемента(ов) и используй его. Тебе ведь все равно, ты работаешь с строкой в бинарном виде.

Хорошо, идем другим путем. Делаем срез текстовой строки:

```
sliceLine := []byte(charLine)
fmt.Println(sliceLine) // byte это алиас на тип uint8, т.е. сейчас видим бинарное представление данных, как сделано для типа string с приведением к строке. Делая срез мы можем указать какой тип использовать: uint8 или int32 (rune)
```

Вопрос

2. Почему для среза, я не могу указать тип uint16. Для кириллицы хватит за глаза.  А потом просто как обычно привести из числа в строчку штатной функцией string() ?

Вопрос имеет некоторую практическую ценность. Допустим я большой жмот :) и мне  жалко выделять в памяти 4 байта на каждый символ, используя rune. Поэтому хочу выделять только 2 байта используя uint16 (думаю нет смысла для символа учитывать sign bit => кириллица влезет) но golang меня не понимает. Или я его :)
Да, uint8 (byte) не устраивает тем, что кодирует кириллицу по несколько байт и работать с ней как с массивом символов в бинарном виде – не удобно.

Согласно [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
в uint16 => 2byte влезет как кириллица, так 80% всего, что потребуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Потому что разработчики логично решили использовать UTF-8. Это их выбор.
2. Потому что для кириллицы хватит, а для чего-то другого и нет. Что делать в таком случае при конвертации в `uint16`? Поэтому и сделан выбор -- либо байты (UTF-8) (как собственно строки в Go и хранятся), либо по 4 байта для быстрой обработки, когда любой символ кодируется одним числом. Если вы хотите использовать по 2 байта, используйте UTF-16 с помощью пакета [unicode/utf16](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/), кириллица будет помещаться в одно слово.

   ```
   // получаем срез []uint16
   line := utf16.Encode([]rune(charLine))

   // используем
   ...
   ```

Важный момент: то, что не будет помещаться в 2 байта, будет использовать два элемента этого среза, но если вы заведомо знаете, что у вас все будет помещаться, то на это можно не обращать внимания.

Comment: Спасибо за пакет. Спасибо за stackoverflow на русском. :) Реально очень хорошие ответы в отличии от тостера :) Что касается символа в golang, из недостоверных источников (чей то блог) было вычитано, что в Go каждый символ представляется типом rune в кодировке UTF-8. Но, дергая его как массив я вижу тип byte. А не rune (int32) - что я не правильно понимаю?

Comment: Что-то неправильное в этом источнике написано. Строки в Go -- неизменяемые срезы байтов, представляющие собой валидный UTF-8 (если только ничего не "намутить" с помощью `\xNN`). То есть символ занимает от 1 до 4 байт. Если же конвертировать строку в `[]rune` -- то каждый элемент представляет один символ в виде *code point* Unicode, без всякой кодировки (UTF-8 или что бы то ни было).

Comment: Все хорошо описано в официальном блоге (https://blog.golang.org/strings), но, увы, на английском.

Comment: Стараюсь изучать параллельно анг. с изучением первого для себя ЯП. Но анг. документация, пока очень сложна для меня. Поэтому пришел сюда. Постараюсь влиться в Ваш дружный коллектив и тоже отвечать на вопросы. Вадим, жму руку - вопрос исчерпан, вам большое спасибо. Да, когда обратился к с строке как к массиву у меня произошел сбой в мозге, потому, что ожидал увидеть тип rune согласно вот [этой статьи](http://dafter.ru/duf/golang/135.html) - Базовые типы. Хотя, возможно я просто не правильно понял контекст сказанного в этом обзоре.

Comment: По поводу `rune` там неверно лишь то, что используется кодировка UTF-8. Там не сказано, что этот тип используется в `string`.

Comment: Появился естественно еще один вопрос. Использовал библиотеку utf16, теперь как конвертить в текстовое представление?  Штатная функция string() меня не понимает. Предполагаю просит знакомые ей типы uint8 или int32. Неужели мне придется делать промежуточное сохранение в int32, ведь понижать градус нельзя. Данные похерются. Что подскажете? Так понимаю нужно еще одну библиотеку подключать для конвертации уже в тип string. Думаю моя затея сэкономить вылезет мне боком :))

Comment: Либо `string(utf16.Decode(line))`, что, конечно, потребует промежуточного хранения строки по 4 байта на символ, либо самому написать (или найти написанную) функцию конвертирования по одному символу UTF-16 в UTF-8, разобравшись, как данные кодируются в этих кодировках. Я, честно говоря, не могу представить, зачем вам понадобилась мизерная экономия в 2 байта на символ. То есть я уверен, что такие задачи могут возникнуть, но вряд ли это ваш случай.

Comment: Да, экономия на спичках выливается в лишние телодвижения и подключения over-дохера не нужных библиотек.В моем случае гораздо проще использовать[]byte + функции из пакета strings, таких как strings.Index() или strings.LastIndex(), гарантирующих целостность границ символов при извлечении среза. Однако, сея затея была интересна для понимания многих тонкостей, а главное возможное появление библиотеки, которая требуется для таких задач. Возможно однажды, здесь появится на нее ссылка. Следовательно вопрос считаю в большей степени полезный с учетом твоих отличных ответов. Еще раз спасибо тебе, Вадим.

Comment: вообщем и в целом, было бы не плохо иметь в GO еще один базовый тип допустим char как в Си (там он правда тоже в 1байт), только с хранением в uint16. Но это мечты.